# DirectoryInfo.ToString works differently on Parent directories?

Tags: c#, .net, io, directoryinfo

Why [`DirectoryInfo.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) sometimes returns the `FullName`(path) and sometimes just the directory-`Name`? I just noticed it because i've tried to concatenate a parent-directory-name with the directory-name here:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unpack\folder1");
DirectoryInfo parentDir = dir.Parent;
var dirAndParent = $"{parentDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{dir.Name}";
```

To my suprise this works and returned the desired part `unpack\folder1`.
I thought i would need `parentDir.Name` instead of `parentDir`, similar to `dir.Name`. If i remove `Name` from `dir.Name` i will get the full-path of the directory. But the parent `DirectoryInfo` instance just returns the `Name`.

Where is it documented, what is the difference between both `DirectoryInfo` instances?

```
Console.WriteLine("dir.ToString: \t\t" + dir.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("parentDir.ToString: \t" + parentDir.ToString());
```

Will output the `FullName`(path) for `dir` and the `Name` for `parentDir`:

```
dir.ToString:           C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unpack\folder1
parentDir.ToString:     unpack
```

`parentDir.FullName` returns also the full path: `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unpack`

---

Maybe a bug but certainly a lack of documentation. 
The lesson is clear: never use [`DirectoryInfo.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) or pass the instance into methods like `String.Format`(or string interpolation) which uses `ToString` implicitly if the `DirectoryInfo` instance was initialized via [`DirectoryInfo.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd187961.aspx). Since you often don't know how it was initialized it's better to avoid `DirectoryInfo.ToString` in general. This bug(inconsistent, non-transparent behaviour) might be fixed in future which would break the code.

Comment: Not an answer, but why not just use Path.Combine and provide the names directly instead of string concatenation with the path separator char? I think you might get even different results when parent is the drive root--I might be misremembering but I think `new DirectoryInfo("c:").ToString()` already includes the path separator. Though I admit the results you experience are weird/interesting so I'm looking forward to someone's answer. If you do a `Refresh()` on the parent does the output change? Could possibly be related to the Caching and normalization of file system entries/names .Net does.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: you're right, in this case `Path.Combine(parentDir.Name, dir.Name)` would be better and also avoids this issue because you can't pass a `DirectoryInfo` instance to `Path.Combine`, you have to be explicit. But it doesn't explain or fix this issue. `DirectoryInfo.ToString` is broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked into the `DirectoryInfo` source code provided by Microsoft and you can easily reproduce this behavior. They are using the [Internal constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs,9b686901e4153de3,references) `internal DirectoryInfo(String fullPath, bool junk)` when you invoke `Parent` property.

The below reproduces your issue without calling `Parent`:

```
var dirInfoUsingPublicConstructor = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");
Console.WriteLine(dirInfoUsingPublicConstructor.ToString());

var ctor = typeof(DirectoryInfo).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                                | BindingFlags.Instance).First();
var dirInfoUsingInternalConstructor = 
            ctor.Invoke(new object[] { @"C:\Test", false }) as DirectoryInfo;
Console.WriteLine(dirInfoUsingInternalConstructor.ToString());
```

Results:

```
C:\Test
Test
```

Internally, that constructor uses `Path.GetFileName` to get the result. Which returns the folder name only. I have no idea about the reason behind this distinction in the implementation detail. It might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ToString definition from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) it seems like a call to this method returns the original path, that was passed in.

In your call

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\unpack\folder1");
```

you passed in the full path of the Directory. By accessing the Parent Node using the Property you did not explicitly call the constructor with the full path. Internally it may have used the relative path.